# How to arrange all xticks on the x axis evenly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I'd like to evenly spread all xticks labels on X axis, even they are integers. So instead of this:
[image]

I'd like the 10000,20000,50000,100000,200000 to be treated as text labels and arranged evenly.

I have this code (not imported parts ommited):

```
xmajorgrids,
xtick=data,
ymin=800,
ymax=950,
scaled ticks=false,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
```

And then this:

```
\addplot[draw=none,fill=mycolor1!20, postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=mycolor1}
] table[row sep=crcr]
{%
10000   807 \\
25000   823 \\
50000   884 \\
100000  887 \\
200000  888 \\
};
```

I tried to work with symbolic x ticks, but it didn't work as intended.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find an answer, maybe it will help somebody. I added one line of code above `xtick=data`:

```
symbolic x coords={10000,25000,50000,100000,200000},
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

A more automated way of doing what you want is to use the `xticklabels from table` feature. Unfortunately currently the labels are interpreted as "symbolic coords", i.e. as text, and thus no number formatting can be applied. Of course to use this feature the table has to be given as a file or a loaded table ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableread{
        10000   807
        25000   823
        50000   884
        100000  887
        200000  888
    }{\datatable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=800,
        ymax=950,
        xmajorgrids,
        xtick=data,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added stuff
        xticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index] 0},
        xtick distance=1,
        table/x expr=\coordindex,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot table [y index=1] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]